# Is it safe to backup only my replication database?

Tags: postgresql, backup, replication

I have this production database (let's call it database `a`) running in the production server `A`. I have a replication (let's call it database `b`) of this `A` db running in the server `B`.

Right now, I have a backup script running on the `A` server. It's burdening `A` with too much processing and networking ...

I would like to stop backing up the `a` db and backup only `b` with the same script. I would move the script currently running on `A` server to `B`.

Theoretically both databases are equal, but I'm not sure if it is good practice and if it is safe enough.

What do you think? Is it safe to do backups only on replication databases instead of the production ones?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely safe and commendable to run backups from a standby server.

If you use `pg_dump`, you may run into replication conflicts that make `pg_dump` fail. To avoid that (at the price of delaying replication), set `max_standby_streaming_delay = -1`.